# Align image to to center LinearLayout from code

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation from `wix` in my react-native application, So for showing the splash screen in my app I have to write the android layout in code in this class.

Since I have not worked in android I am unable to align image and a some text to center in LinearLayout.

[image]

This is how the mockup looks like.

Here is the code I have written so far.

```
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;

 public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {
    @Override
    public LinearLayout createSplashLayout() {
        LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        ImageView logoView = new ImageView(this);
        logoView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.icon);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        logoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        logoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.welcome);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        frame.addView(imageView);
        frame.addView(logoView);
        view.addView(frame);
        return view;
    }
 }
```

If someone could help me figure out how to achieve this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(llParams);
    RelativeLayout view = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout
            .LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);

    ImageView bgView = new ImageView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bgParam =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout
                    .LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    bgView.setLayoutParams(bgParam);
    bgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.welcome);
    bgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.addView(bgView);

    ImageView logoView = new ImageView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout
            .LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    logoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    logoView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.icon);
    view.addView(logoView);
    linearLayout.addView(view);
    return linearLayout;
```

Comment: @warl0ck I have updated the answer. With one background image and another image icon at center.

Comment: works perfectly thanks :), could you please also tell if there is a way to resize this center icon ?

Comment: and I think instead of `FILL_PARENT` it should be `MATCH_PARENT` as its deprecated from lollipop as android studio gave warning

Comment: Yes. you can change the size the icon by giving values in the line
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40,40);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for set image on center and set Layout background image.

```
            LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this); 
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.example_appwidget_preview));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            ImageView logoView = new ImageView(this);
            logoView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            view.addView(logoView);
```

I hope it will work for you !